# Problem with the position-order of my custom listview elements

Tags: android, listview, webview, position

I have created a custom listview that have one webview per element.

My problem is that when I click on an element, it takes the bad element-positon.

Here is my custom listview

```
public class ListViewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public ArrayList<String> mywebview;
public Activity context;
public LayoutInflater inflater;

public ListViewCustomAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> mywebview) {
    //super();
    this.mywebview = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.context = context;
    this.mywebview = mywebview;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mywebview.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return mywebview.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    WebView mywebviewholder;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylistview2, null, false);
        holder.mywebviewholder = (WebView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.weblistview);

        holder.mywebviewholder
                .setOnTouchListener(new my.student.application.WebViewClickListener(
                        holder.mywebviewholder, parent, position));
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.mywebviewholder.loadDataWithBaseURL("", mywebview.get(position)
            .toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
    return convertView;
}
```

my webview click listener

```
public class WebViewClickListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
private int position;
private ViewGroup vg;
private WebView wv;

public WebViewClickListener(WebView wv, ViewGroup vg, int position) {
    this.vg = vg;
    this.position = position;
    this.wv = wv;
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        sendClick();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void sendClick() {
    ListView lv = (ListView) vg;
    lv.performItemClick(wv, position, 0);
}
```

Thanks for your help

Edit: Something weird I found out. If in my listview.xml I change the height size of my webview, when I click on an element, It changes the position of the element

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="3dip">
<WebView android:id="@+id/weblistview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dip"></WebView>
```

With this heigh the order if I have 5 elements is: 2 1 0 2 1

I really don't see where is the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `getView()`, you are setting the touch listener to the view in the holder. That code only gets called for the first visible elements in the list (when `convertView` is `null`)

You should be setting the listener to the current item right before returning the `convertView` so your code should look like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylistview2, null, false);
        holder.mywebviewholder = (WebView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.weblistview);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.mywebviewholder
                .setOnTouchListener(new my.student.application.WebViewClickListener(
                        holder.mywebviewholder, parent, position));
    holder.mywebviewholder.loadDataWithBaseURL("", mywebview.get(position)
            .toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
    return convertView;
}
```

The idea with the holder is to avoid searching through the xml for every findViewByID.

Comment: Ah, finally it's working. Thanks a lot for your answer, now it looks like more simple and logic.